# Simplifying the expression $\frac{x + y}{x - y} + \frac{1}{x + y} - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{y^2 - x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you tell me why my answer is wrong?

$$\frac {x+y} {x-y} + \frac 1 {x+y} - \frac {x^2+y^2} {y^2-x^2} = \frac {x^2 + y^2} {x^2-y^2} + \frac {x-y} {x^2-y^2} + \frac {x^2+y^2} {x^2-y^2} = 2x^2 + 2y^2 + x-y$$

Comment: Should it be the title?? I don' think so.

Comment: It looks like you tried $(x+y)*(x+y) = x^2+y^2$ (on the first term) which is not generally true.

Comment: $(x+y)^2\ne x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You have also changed the $-$ in front of the third fraction into a $+$.

Answer (score 2):

$(x+y)(x+y)$ does not equal $x^2+y^2$. It equals $(x+y)^2$ or $x^2+2xy+y^2$.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

on the second line, the first expression you have $$\frac{x+y}{x-y} = \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2} $$ it should be $$\frac{x+y}{x-y} = \frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2-y^2} = \frac{x^2+2xy + y^2}{x^2-y^2}$$ instead.  the rest of them  looks good.